Windows Batch For loop not repeated as expected
Target:
I want to split a string by a delimiter in a for loop of a batch program, so a substring is split and printed out in each iteration.
Problem:
However, I found the for loop does not repeat as expected but just executes for only once, although the variable my_str does change its value correctly.
So what are the causes of problems?
PS:
FYI, the number of substrings in my_str variable will be unknown, so I did not use token option in for loop.
My batch program:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "my_delim=`"
set "my_str=I am A`I am B`I am C`"

for /F "delims=%my_delim%" %%A in ("!my_str!") do (
    echo inside loop started
    echo A value is [%%A]
    
    set "my_str=!my_str:*%my_delim%=!"
    echo remaining my_str is [!my_str!]
    echo inside loop ended
    echo ------------------------------------
)
echo exited loop
pause

Actual result:
inside loop started
A value is [I am A]
remaining my_str is [I am B`I am C`]
inside loop ended
------------------------------------
exited loop
Press any key to continue . . . 

Expected result:
inside loop started
A value is [I am A]
remaining my_str is [I am B`I am C`]
inside loop ended
------------------------------------
inside loop started
A value is [I am B]
remaining my_str is [I am C`]
inside loop ended
------------------------------------
inside loop started
A value is [I am C]
remaining my_str is []
inside loop ended
------------------------------------
exited loop
Press any key to continue . . . 


Please open a command prompt, run for /? and read the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. The behavior you expect from for /F does not match with the documented behavior of this command. See also the Microsoft online documentation of the Windows command for and the two FOR /F pages in A-Z index of Windows CMD commands.

set "my_str=I am A`I am B`I am C`"

:again    
for /F "delims=%my_delim%" %%A in ("!my_str!") do (
    echo inside loop started
    echo A value is [%%A]
    
    set "my_str=!my_str:*%my_delim%=!"
    echo remaining my_str is [!my_str!]
    echo inside loop ended
    echo ------------------------------------
)
if defined my_str goto again

Should fix your problem (but you've missed the point of for)
{UNTESTED}

Good solution for the example in the question. Just an info: It fails to process correct a string like "I ! A`;I am B`I & C`" (without surrounding ") defined with already enabled delayed variable expansion with set "my_str=I ^! A`;I am B`I & C`". There is output in this case A value is [I  A] with missing ! and then the code runs into an endless loop which does not output anything. Well, we don't know which characters and combination of characters are possible in the string to split up into substrings as not specified by Grace.

The following code is a technique that uses string replacement to make the delimiter into a linefeed. By doing this, the FOR /F command thinks there are multiple lines of output to iterate.
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "my_str=I am A`I am B`I am C`"
for /F "delims=" %%G in (^"!my_str:^`^=^
% Do NOT remove this line %
!^") do (
  echo A value is %%G
  echo remaining value is !my_str:*%%G`=!
)

And here is the output.
D:\My Drive\BatchFiles\SO\78352559>so.bat
A value is I am A
remaining value is I am B`I am C`
A value is I am B
remaining value is I am C`
A value is I am C
remaining value is

I have another concept that I am going to post shortly as well that doesn't require a FOR /F command.

Good solution for the example in the question. Just an info: It fails to process correct a string like "I ! A`;I am B`I & C`" (without surrounding ") defined with already enabled delayed variable expansion with set "my_str=I ^! A`;I am B`I & C`". There is output in this case A value is I  A with missing !, ;I am B is skipped and last is output correct I & C. Well, we don't know which characters and combination of characters are possible in the string to split up into substrings as not specified by Grace.
